# how to identify start node in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have below xml.

Expected txt Output is:

```
stAddresscitystatezip
1Esd94587enamestAddrcitystatezip
```

I want to make a generic xslt code. So i want to identify all child node of record and put this into one line for each child node.

```
<rcrd>
  <Trans_rcrd>
     <stAdd>stAddress</stAdd>
     <city>city</city>
     <state>state</state>
     <zip>zip</zip>
  </Trans_rcrd>
  <Empler_rcrd>
     <rcrdID>1Esd</rcrdID>
     <empID>94587</empID>
     <eName>ename</eName>
     <stAdd>stAddr</stAdd>
     <city>city</city>
     <state>state</state>
     <zip>zip</zip>
  </Empler_rcrd>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "generic" means agnostic of the element names then you can try

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="*" separator=""/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

which simply processes the child elements of the root element and outputs the concatenated values of the grandchildren.

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nbUY4kj

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. But When i am keeping this code into netweaver development studio i am getting below output. 

stAddress
1Esd

But in online tool shared by u is giving perfect output. what went wrong ?

Comment: You have to understand that now, in 2017, we have three versions of XSLT, version 3 is the current, finished this year, and supported by Saxon 9.8 and by Altova 2017/2018, version 2, finished in 2007, supported by various processors like Saxon 9, XmlPrime, older Altova versions, and the ancient version 1, specified in 1999, and supported in old tools like Saxon 6.5, Xalan 2.7, various Microsoft processors like XslCompiledTransform and the various MSXML versions, all C based scripting languages like PHP making use of libxslt. So depending on your processor you only have XSLT 1 support.

Answer (score 0):

This may get you going.  Step through it in the debugger to understand it.

```
<xsl:template match="rcrd">
  <!-- Select the child nodes for each rcrd. -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="rcrdChildNodes"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This template will process the child nodes of rcrd. -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="rcrdChildNodes">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="outputChildNodes"/>
  <!-- Carriage return character. -->
  <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Process the child nodes of Trans_rcrd and Empler_rcrd -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="outputChildNodes">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: EJP - The edits you made to my code broke the code.  If you are going to edit someone's code, you should at a minimum test your results.  But, I will make an explanation for what I think you were doing in another comment.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> can get you in trouble.  Especially, if you are going for generic.  Someone might put spaces in the XML to affect the eventual output.  <city>Chicago</city><space> </space><zip>12345</zip>.  You will loose the space.